# Snowflake Query - How can I get an specific set of users with an specific kind of name (all this users have @domain) from all the users?

Tags: sql, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I am starting with the Snowflake stuff and I would like to get all the users that contain the '@domain' as a name.

How can this be possible?

Im trying:

```
select * FROM users where name like '@domain';
```

However I am still getting all the users without any exception.

Any help or advise would be appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

You need to use wildcards:

```
SELECT * FROM users WHERE name ILIKE '%@domain';
```